# how to delete a parse user from an android application?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm making an android app that have 2 UserTypes an administrator and regular users the administrator have the ability to control the Parse database edit, add and delete but i have come to a problem concerning the delete user here is my code but it is not working

```
final String userId = user.getUserId();
         ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
         query.whereEqualTo("objectid", userId);

         query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {



            public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 try {
                    object.delete();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Successfully deleted Project"+userId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //prog.dismiss();

                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
```

any  help will be appreciated thx

Answer (score 6):

A user cannot delete another user from the client.  It can be done in cloud code with `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()`.

(As an aside, it looks like the posted code wasn't even fetching the user by id.  It would stand to reason that `whereEqualTo("objectId", someObjectId)` would find an object, but parse provides a special form of query for this called `getInBackground()`.  [See the doc for Parse.Query](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/).

EDIT - In cloud code, the function would go something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("deleteUserWithId", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var userId = request.params.userId;
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.get(userId).then(function(user) {
        return user.destroy();
    }).then(function() {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

From the client (though I'm a java dilettante):

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("userId", userId);
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("deleteUserWithId", params, new FunctionCallback<Float>() {
   void done(Object result, ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
           // success
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the cloud code can i access it from the android app?

Comment: There's a little admin to be done to setup.  See the doc here.  https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#cloud-code.  Once you're setup, you push javascript to parse which runs in a nodejs server.  There's a client api to call by name the functions you deploy.  I can post what one of those would look like if you want.

Comment: @GeorgesBadra - did this answer the question?

Comment: @danh you said a user can not delete another user from a client app. but you posted the code of Java, which I assume is for android. isnt it contradicting to your first statement?

Comment: @HaroonKhan, there are two blocks of code given in the answer.  The first is JS, to be executed on the server, which is permitted to delete a user.  The second just shows how you invoke the server code from Java.

Comment: okay, my bad. i initially thought you are calling a sdk function.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        user.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                   //user deleted
                } else {
                    ccd.showDialog(mContext, e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The master key can be accessed via the Parse Rest API.  Just write a Parse Cloud Code function to delete a user using the master key then call that function from the admin account using the Parse Android API.